# MySQL : group records by datetime ignoring the "seconds"

Tags: mysql, date, group-by

I have a table with thousands of records like this:

```
[Row]    ActionTime              Score
=======================================
[#1]   2011-08-06 12:30:15       30
[#2]   2011-08-06 12:30:20       50
[#3]   2011-08-06 12:30:47       40
[#4]   2011-08-06 12:40:12       30
[#5]   2011-08-06 12:40:28       10
[#5]   2011-08-06 12:45:12       60
```

I want to group the data in minutes and find the maximum score of each group.

So the result is like this:

```
[Row]  ActionTime (without "second")          Score        
========================================================
[#1]   2011-08-06 12:30:00                     50  
[#2]   2011-08-06 12:40:00                     30
[#3]   2011-08-06 12:45:00                     60
```

How can I do this through MySQL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select 
date_format(actiontime,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00') as act_time,
max(score) as greater
from table
group by act_time
```

Comment: it is worth noting, that if you use printf to format queries(or some derivatives of this function), escape ie '%Y' putting '%%Y'(or printf will try to put arguments in that place-by '%%' it treats this as normal string).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to select the formatted field, you can use it directly in `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
GROUP BY date_format(datetime_field, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00');
```